# How export juxtaposed layers in a PNG using The Gimp?

Tags: gimp, export, png, animation

The Gimp allows you to save animations in the GIF format, but I wondered if there were a way to export the animation layers in one PNG, with every layer juxtaposed next to (the right of) the previous one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you have to find a script to merge all layers into a single one, such as those used to make sprite sheets, for instance [this one](http://registry.gimp.org/node/20943).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help with *gimp*, but the **ImageMagick** package has lots of command line tools to manipulate images. For example you can split an animated `file.gif` into separate `target.*.png` files with

```
convert -coalesce file.gif target.%04d.png
```

You can then place all these together into a single `out.png` with

```
montage target.*.png out.png
```

Example gif [image] (from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/script_k.gif)), and resulting montage [image]

Comment: I'll check that out. I hope it can handle something else than GIF, since that'd limit me to 256 colors.